# Update table if table contains more than 500000 rows of data

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have around 500000 rows (image url) in my database table, my task is to check if image url is responding or not then I need to update table with the result like (if responding then yes else no).

First I thought I will take all rows into a dataset and update all rows in the dataset then I will update my database, but when I was loading data into the dataset I was getting error like `outofmemoryexception`. I was not able to get all data into the dataset.

I thought I will update rows one by one, but its taking too much time and every time database is hitting which is not good. I an working on asp.net application using c# and SQL

So if you have better idea then please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by *database is heating* ?!?!?!?! Your disk is getting hot?!?!?!? Seriously - what do you mean, this is very unclear....

Comment: Why don't you load data in chunks of say 1000 at a time, process them within context of a transaction and then save & commit the transaction. Row by row is going to be very slow, a half a million-row dataset could definitely cause memory problems depending on what's in it.

Comment: Which columns you are selecting? If you select just `ID` and `Url` columns, the 500k records should not cause out of memory.
You can also use `DataReader` in a loop instead of loading all the data in data set.

Comment: Sorry , not heating its hitting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DataSet` use `SqlDataReader` to read and process the data in the loop.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `Stored Procedure` or calling `Functions` inside DB? I assume, that you're using some ORM tool (or even raw ADO.NET) to get all values and then update values in application. Fine. But have you considered not downloading results and operate only in database using mentioned tools?

Comment: He's already said he's using a dataset, not an ORM. Also, how's he going to check if an image URL is responding from a stored proc or function ?

Comment: Simply. He can try reach **one** image in database and then, run stored procedure without processing whole table in application.

Comment: He is trying to see if the image exists (reach) on the internet not in database.